# How to know whether the page is selected from Swipe or Click of Tab of Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tabs

I have a ViewPager which Toolbar tabs.

I have to know how many times user clicked tabs and how many times user swiped and selected a page.

I am using ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() for this purpose.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         // Here i am sending the GA event
    }

    @Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
  });
```

OnPageSelected is called for both click and swipe of page. 
How will I differentiate the page selected is from click of tabs or its from swipe of Viewpager ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution. I am basing on single variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // remember last action
    private Action lastAction = Action.RESET;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ...

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
                // No-op
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                if (lastAction == Action.RESET) {
                    lastAction = Action.SWIPE;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected: SWIPED");
                } else {
                    lastAction = Action.RESET;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
                // No-op
            }
        });

        mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (lastAction == Action.RESET) {
                    lastAction = Action.SELECT;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected: SELECTED");
                } else {
                    lastAction = Action.RESET;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // No-op
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // No-op
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Limitation:

Content for viewPager must be loaded before adding listeners because this solutions is basing on ordered calls (onTabSelected, onPageSelected).

Preview:

[image]

Comment: where will i find that ACTION class?

Comment: It is just an enum.

Answer (score 3):

**In this example I will be checking if the user selected the page at index 1 by swiping or by tapping the tab:**

Note: You can use tabLayout.getChildAt(0) to get the main sliding layout, and

```
((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(desiredPosition) //to get the tab at desired position
```

Using this, we add onClickListener to the desired tab and once clicked, its onClick() method will be called first followed by the onTabSelected() method of the TabSelectedListener of the TabLayout.

```
 private Boolean tabClicked = false; //variable which determines after entering the onTabSelected() method, if onClick was called or not

 ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tabClicked = true;
            }
        });


  tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tab.getPosition()==1){
                    if(tabClicked){ 
                         //your tab was clicked, do work here
                    }
                    else{ 
                         //your tab was swiped, do some work here
                    }
                    tabClicked = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The tabview you use, is a textview. So there will be onclicklistener for this textview. You could track the tab click on onClick() method of listener!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

````
 fun onTabClickedListener(callback: String.() -> Unit){
        tabContainer?.let { tabContainer->
            for (i in 0 until tabContainer.tabCount) {
                val text = tabContainer.getTabAt(i)?.text.toString() ?: ""
                (tabContainer.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(i).tag = text
                (tabContainer.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener {
                    callback(text)
                }
            }

        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions and they did not work for me. The below solution worked for me.

```
enter code here class TestFragment : Fragment{
 private var lastAction = Action.RESET

 private fun addPagerListener() {
    viewPager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            when (lastAction) {
                Action.RESET -> Unit
                Action.SWIPE -> onPageSwiped(position)
                Action.CLICKED -> onTabClicked(position)
            }
            lastAction = Action.RESET
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && lastAction == Action.RESET) {
                lastAction = Action.SWIPE
            }
        }
    })

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            if (lastAction == Action.RESET) {
                lastAction = Action.CLICKED
            }
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    })
}

fun onTabClicked(position: Int) {//action to be here
}

fun onPageSwiped(position: Int) {//action to be here
}
}
```

and here is the enum

```
private enum class Action {
RESET, SWIPE, CLICKED
```

}